# Md-Autocomplete does not call search function

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to display an md-autocomplete in a table like this:

```
                <td>
                    <md-autocomplete md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item="enumvals" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
                                     md-item-text="item" md-min-length="0" md-no-cache="true" placeholder="Search..." md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
                        <md-item-template>
                                <span class="item-title">
                                    <span> {{item}} </span>
                                </span>
                        </md-item-template>
                    </md-autocomplete>
                </td>
```

But the md-autocomplete looks strange, I'm guessing this is a css error, but more importantly nothing happens when I type in it, the search function is defined as such:

```
$scope.querySearch = function (query) {
    console.dir('Entered');
    var results = query.length > 0 ? $scope.enumValsSearch.filter(function (item) {
        var tempItem = item.toLowerCase();
        var tempQuery = query.toLowerCase();
        return (tempItem.indexOf(tempQuery) !== -1);
    }) : $scope.enumValsSearch;
    console.dir(results);
    return results.slice(0, 200);
}
```

The web console doesn't display anything either

Comment: It works fine here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2iz1qSqEfEkxvHZvkfDG?p=info

Comment: I've imported both the js and css files properly and my syntax appears to be correct based on your link, and my data structure is properly populated, but nothing happens on search, not even the console.dir statement to indicate that its entered the search method

Comment: Change this plunker based on your controller and items, then send me the link..

Comment: It works here also (with your code).. http://plnkr.co/edit/amgk9zY1Y84qguW73XNP?p=preview

Comment: I've got it working in other pages as well but it does not work in this specific form, could you help me with that?